# Make maven parent project test all modules before deploying any of them

Tags: java, maven

I have a traditional maven setup with parent project and a number of modules what are sub-projects. When I do `mvn deploy`, it runs the full lifecycle (including `test`) up to `deploy` for each project in sequence (depth-first). I would like to avoid deploying any subprojects if any of projects fails to build. In other words I would like the `deploy` of the whole parent project to be "all or nothing". Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your remote repository is a Sonatype Nexus Pro instance, then the "Staging" facility of Nexus Pro will allow for atomic publishing to the repository proper.

If you are using Jenkins, there is a delayed deployment plugin that will deploy all your artifacts as a post-build (or very post-build) action (doesn't mind too much which repository manager you use)

Finally, one of my medium-long-term goals for the mrm-maven-plugin @ codehaus is to allow local staging of deployment so that you will be able to do something like

```
mvn mrm:catch-deploy deploy mrm:push-deploy
```

*BUT* that last one is not written yet!

Comment: I'm changing the accepted answer to this one because I think you're right to suggest using a CI server for this rather than maven, that is the approach I'm going to take.

Comment: Stephen, which Jenkins plugin are you referring to for delayed deploy?

Comment: Not referring to any specific plugin

Answer (score 8):

Maven itself can't do this (yet). Currently, the build process runs all targets on each module individually. There are plans to allow targets to see the big picture but that's probably for Maven 4.

In the mean time, you can use a little shell script:

```
 mvn clean install && mvn deploy -DskipTests=true
```

The first run builds everything. The second run won't do much (all the code is already compiled and the long tests are skipped), so it's pretty fast.

I actually prefer this approach because my script also replaces any existing `distributionManagement` elements with the ones for my company's cache. This means I can deploy any project for my company without needing to make any changes to the original POM. Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ ! -e pom.xml ]]; then
    echo "Missing pom.xml" 1>&2
    exit 1
fi

sed \
    -e '/<distributionManagement>/,/<\/distributionManagement>/d' \
    -e '/<\/project/d' \
    pom.xml > pom-deploy.xml || exit 1

cat >> pom-deploy.xml  <<EOF


    <!-- ADDED BY $0 -->
    <distributionManagement>
        ... whatever you need ...
    </distributionManagement>
</project>
EOF

mvn -f pom-deploy.xml clean install && \
    mvn -f pom-deploy.xml deploy -DskipTests=true && \
    rm pom-deploy.xml

exit 0
```

[gist](https://gist.github.com/3852490)